# JavaScript Import file by absolute path

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a module named `foo` in a dependencies directory:

```
import foo from '../dependencies/foo'; // works fine
```

The issue is that the import should be on a different path because it's deployed in an AWS dependency layer (different path). Something like this:

```
import foo from '/opt/dependencies/foo';
```

But I am getting this error:

> Cannot find module '/opt/dependencies/foo' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

I can use a `require()` but it gives me a warning telling me to use an `import` statement instead.

```
const foo = require('/opt/dependencies/foo');
```

What can I do to avoid this error while keeping the /opt path?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an the ES6 [dynamic `import()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import), although it is asynchronous. If you're using an environment that supports top-level `await`, then you can simply do this:

```
const foo = await import('/opt/dependencies/foo.js');
```

If you're using an older version of node (you'll know because you'll get an error), then you'll need to wrap your whole program in an async function (the technical term is an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)). Like this:

```
(async () => {
  const foo = await import('/opt/dependencies/foo.js');

  /* rest of your program */
})();
```

Comment: I get the same error with await import

Comment: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.ts(1378)

Comment: @TiagoSilva Yes. If your environment isn't configured to those settings, then you'll need to use my second piece of code, or upgrade :)